# Stored Procedures in Teradata

Tags: sql, stored-procedures, teradata

I have created the following stored procedure in teradata

```
REPLACE procedure dbc.test_sp(OUT max_contact number)
BEGIN
   DECLARE max_contact1 number;

   SELECT max(contact) into max_contact1 
   from testSequon.TestEmployee_SK_Contacts;

   SET max_contact = max_contact1;  

END;
```

I am calling it as :

```
CALL dbc.test_sp(var)
```

Now I want to access 'var' outside. How do I do that?

I have successfully executed the procedure but am unable to access the out variable

Answer (score 0):

The output variable of a stored procedure can be accessed by assigning a value to a variable in the calling environment. In your case, you have defined the output variable as "max_contact" in the stored procedure.

To access the value of the "max_contact" variable outside the stored procedure, you can modify your CALL statement by providing a variable to receive the output value.
U can try this:

```
DECLARE @output_variable number;

CALL dbc.test_sp(@output_variable);

SELECT @output_variable;
```

Comment: The reference to "in the calling environment" is correct, but Teradata SQL does not natively support user variables (DECLARE). The calling environment would be some programming or scripting language.